# Asterisk AMI Originate: Without Extension Local Ringing

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami, pbx

I'm using a PHP script to retireive variables from a URL and create a call using AMI's action Originate.
The phone of the extension making the call rings first and only when answered the "real" call is being made.
I know this is a known issue and I have read about all kinds of solution for this but didn't fully understood any of them and got it to work.

What should I do in order to skip this local ring?
Please try to elaborate,
and even more if the solution lies within the contexts and dialplans.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use other softswitch. There are no way "fix" that in asterisk.

Only variant is do twice call to dynamic conference or Wait extension, conference will autoanswer and bridge(if use Wait, you have brodge yourself via ami). But if you do so, YOU are responsible for hangup.